# I want to create a messagebox when the sqlite3.IntegrityError: appears but its not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

I want to create a messagebox when the `sqlite3.IntegrityError` appears but it's  not working

I try with try except an if else

```
def data_b(*args): 
    import sqlite3 

    conection = sqlite3.Connection('annuaire_telephobque.db')
    cursorr = conection.cursor() 
    cursorr.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS a_t_users(row_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL ,user_f_name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE, user_l_name TEXT  NOT NULL UNIQUE ,use_number TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE)")

    f_get=str(nam0.get()) 
    l_get=str(l_nam0.get())
    n_get=str(numero0.get())  
    try:
        cursorr = conection.cursor() 
        cursorr.execute("INSERT INTO a_t_users (user_f_name, user_l_name ,use_number) VALUES (?,?,?)",(f_get,l_get,n_get)) 
        conection.commit() 

    except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
        cursorr.close()
        conection.commit()
        conection.close()
        print('karim')
        messagebox.showerror(title='error',message='les information existes deja')
```

Comment: You say it's "not working". What does that mean? Is it throwing an error? Is the window showing the wrong error? Something else?

Comment: want to creat a table with unique value and when inserting a duplicate data it display a messagebox instead sqlite3.IntegrityError but that error persisting and sqlite3.IntegrityError does not display

Comment: Are you saying the table is being created, but no integrity error is being thrown? Have you verified that `f_get`, `l_get`, and `n_get` contain the values you expect? Have you examined the database after the insert to see what got inserted?

Comment: The code works fine and I got the message box when trying to insert duplicate data.

Comment: I found the problem in vscode it does not refresh the modification after this step